# Which catalog is Airflow viewing during initialization of SensorOperator?

Tags: python, airflow

I try open fil during performing **init** method in SensorOperator and get error in Airflow:

> Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/get_stars_and_print.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/airflow/dags/get_stars_and_print.py", line 69, in **init**
> self.starting_stars = self.read_stars_from_file()
> File "/opt/airflow/dags/get_stars_and_print.py", line 72, in read_stars_from_file
> with open(self.stars_filename) as fp:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stars.json'

Here's my code:

```
class GithubStarsSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, repo, stars_filename, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.repo_url = f"http://api.github.com/repos/{repo}"
        self.stars_filename = stars_filename
        self.starting_stars = self.read_stars_from_file()

    def read_stars_from_file(self):
        with open(self.stars_filename) as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
        return data["stars"]
```

There's this file in user directory in Worker. This file was written by Airflow like this:

```
with open(self.stars_filename, "w") as stars:
            json.dump(gh_repo.as_dict(), stars)
```

But when I try to read this during initialization it doesn't see it.

I use Docker Airflow image for my experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to solve and avoid this kind of problems:

- make sure your file is accessible by all the workers and the executor:
  you can add it to the docker image if you are using docker compose or k8s, or attach the a volume containing the file to all the containers/pods.
- provide the full path of the file:
  try to avoid the relative paths `stars.json` and provide the full path like `/path/to/stars.json`
- store the file in remote storage if it's a produced by another task:
  if the file is downloaded or created by another task, you should store it in a remote storage like S3, then in your sensor you can download and read it, in this case you make sure that it's accessible by all the workers